# What could be the regex for null terminated ASCII string?

Tags: ruby, regex, null, terminate

I am reading one file using Ruby and I am able to filter out strings stored in fixed sized formats. But I want to filter variable size string which is left by me in the end using some regex or some other thing.

Right now I am scanning string with following line

```
s.scan(/(.{4})(.{4})(.{4})(.{4})(.{4})(.{4})(.{4})(.{4})(.{4})(.*)/).each do |f,g,h,i,j,k,l,m,n,p|
```

but still want to filter this (. *) part of string by separating null terminated strings from it.
How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't really understand why your regex is the way it is, but `\0` is a null byte used in the regex (or `\x00` if you prefer hex codes).  Basically:

```
"foo\x00bar".split(?\x00)
=> ["foo", "bar"]

"foo\x00bar" =~ /\0/
=> 3
```